# Passing ^C in a vim noremap

Tags: vim, terminal

I use vim (v7.3) combined with guake terminal as an Octave DE on ubuntu 12.10.

If I want to stop a process I can go to the terminal and press ctrl-c. I would like to do this with a remap from within vim.

Now, if I in vim type the sequence

```
:!guake -e "^C"
```

(where ^C indicates the literal character sequence "ctrl-v ctrl-c") the stop command gets send to the guake terminal as if I had pressed ctrl-c while focus was on the terminal. However, when I try to remap a key to the sequence above in my .vimrc as follows:

```
nnoremap <leader>w :!guake -e "^C"<cr>
```

it does not seem to work. When I press ,w ("," is my leader) nothing happens. I suspect that the ^C command gets interpreted by vim to abort the character sequence as if I had typed

```
:!guake -w "
```

and then aborted with ctrl-c.

Is it possible to include the ^C character (ascii 0x03 I believe) in the way that I am trying to do?

If not, any suggestions as to an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the same keys (in Vim's notation) to the mapping as you press them interactively:

```
:nnoremap <leader>w :!guake -e "<C-v><C-c>"<cr>
```